# Creating a new nested model property using Ember-Data

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an API that has a undefined section for properties called `app_data` which is used for storing random data. I'm trying to determine how to get the value from an input on the template and set it on the model as a nested property of `app_data` called tags. I've tried a number of methods but they do not apply any data to the app_data.tags. Any help would be appreciated.

```
App.Photo = DS.Model.extend({
  title: attr(),
  description: attr(),
  image: attr(),
  width: attr(),
  height: attr(),
  important_top: attr(),
  important_left: attr(),
  important_bottom: attr(),
  important_right: attr(),
  created: attr('date'),
  authors: hasMany('author'),
  app_data: {
    tags: []
  },
  imageURL: function() {
    return document.location.origin + '/media/' + this.get('image');
  }.property('image'),
});

App.PhotoseditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('photo');
  },
});

App.PhotoseditController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
    save: function() {
      this.set('app_data.tags', 'test tag');
      this.get('model').save();
    }
  }
});

 <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2>Edit Photo Meta Data</h2>
    <button {{action 'save'}} style="float:right;">Save All</button>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {{#each}}
        <tr>
          <td><img {{bind-attr src="imageURL"}} width="200" /></td>
          <td>{{input title valueBinding="title"}}</td>
          <td>{{input description valueBinding="description"}}</td>
          <td>{{input tags valueBinding="tags"}}</td>
        </tr>
        {{else}}
        <tr>
          <td colspan="6">No photos yet.</td>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
      </tbody>
    </table>
</script>
```

Comment: app_data is not an ember object, that's why calling 'set' on it, does not work, you would need to do something like this.get('app_data').tags.push('test tag')

Comment: Thanks for the help. If I log this.get('app_data') or this.get('app_data').tags I receive undefined. If I try to get and push, like you suggested, I receive an error: `Cannot read property 'tags' of undefined`.

Comment: what I can see in your code is that you have the save action in the 'PhostosController', that's the plural version, so, 'app_data' is not there, it belongs to a Photo, not to an array of photos. So, either the 'save' action should go in the PhotoController, or when calling 'save' pass this(which is the current photo), and in your 'save' action receive a param save: function(photo). and then photo.get('app_data')...

Comment: I had tried to simplify the example so it would be easy to parse but that provided wrong assumptions. I updated it with the model and the actual controller name. When I tried passing the (photo) parameter it returned undefined.

Comment: ok, based in your template, you're doing an 'each', that means you're displaying a bunch of records. The save action is being called in the controller which content is the array of photos. That's why "this.set()" does not work, that's clear, right ?. And since the Save action is 'global' in that template, you can not sent the 'photo' object, because it is not inside your 'each' loop. If it was in your 'each' loop, it would be displayed for each photo.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your meaning. So I should add something like {{input app_data.tags valueBinding="app_data.tags"}} so it's properly appearing in the loop or do I need to somehow include the app_data.tags with attr()?

Comment: what is the user going to write in the tags input field ? and array of values ? like this ? [1,2,3] ? that's not possible. What I am trying to tell you, is the way to push a value to an array. Since app_data is not and ember object, you can not call set on it, you need to do photo.get('app_date').tags.push('whatever tag you want').

Comment: Certainly, I understand that I'll need to loop through the array. However, at the moment I cannot pass photos into the action at all. So it doesn't make a difference at all.

Comment: Ok, look here http://jsfiddle.net/NQKvy/730/ this an example on how you can handle what you want. That's what came to my mind, it is simple, but hope it helps you find the solution.

Comment: This helped quite a bit. Thank you.